# How to redirect color output to a file?

Tags: shell-script, colors, echo

```
echo -e "SUCCESS=$(tput setaf 1)$(tput setab 7)FALSE$(tput sgr 0) Share=$DIR1  \
                                LastCheckedDate=$(date +%Y_%m_%d_%H:%M:%S)" >> $ERROR_LOG
```

In error log I am getting ASCII characters. I need color output to redirect.